What class of subgraphs of the $n$-hypercube graph characterizes the region graphs of arrangements of $n$ hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^d$?
I am looking for a reference that answers or at least discusses the question in the title. I browsed Sergei Ovchinnikov's book "Graphs and Cubes" and several lecture notes on hyperplane arrangements without success. Let me state the relevant definitions below.
Definitions. A hyperplane arrangement $\mathcal{A}$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is a finite family of $\mathcal{A}=\{H_i\}_{i=1}^n$ of distinct hyperplanes $H_i$. A region (or chamber) of a hyperplane arrangement $\mathcal{A}=\{H_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is a connected component of $\mathbb{R}^d\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^n H_i$. Two regions of $\mathcal{A}$ are adjacent if they are separated by a unique hyperplane in $\mathcal{A}$.The region (chamber/dual) graph of $\mathcal{A}$ has as vertices the regions of $\mathcal{A}$ and has as edges pairs of adjacent regions. The region graph of an arrangement of $n$ hyperplanes is a subgraph of the $n$-hypercube graph: we can identify each region $R$ with a vertex of the $n$-hypercube by identifying $R$ with the halfspaces of the hyperplanes in which it is contained.
Question. What class of subgraphs of the $n$-hypercube graph characterizes the region graphs of arrangements of $n$ hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^d$?

The only related paper I could find is a characterization of the tope graphs of affine oriented matroids. But not every affine oriented matroid can be realized as a hyperplane arrangement. The reference is
Knauer, Kolja, and Tilen Marc. "On tope graphs of complexes of oriented matroids." Discrete & Computational Geometry 63.2 (2020): 377-417.
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00454-019-00111-z
